# Where are installed the files of a .deb package with dpkg / apt-get?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, haskell

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.
I have done: `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform-doc`

But I cannot find the corresponding documentation files.

Where could I find them ? Or is there a command to launch so as to find where the `.deb` package has put them in my file system ?

Is there a way to locate them. After reboot `locate` didn't helped me that much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dpkg -L haskell-platform-doc` will list the files installed by that package for you. However, this is a meta package, it does not install much content itself, but pulls in other documentation packages as dependencies. So issue `dpkg-query -f'${Depends}' -W haskell-platform-doc` to find the dependencies, and use `dpkg -L` with those. You should expect `/usr/share/doc/libghc-*-doc/html/index.html` and similar files, which you can view with a web browser (with `file:///` URLs).

Answer (score 4):

given a package `package-filename.deb` file, this command lists the installed files with their location:

```
dpkg --contents package-filename.deb
```

Comment: The location listed is relative to the deb file itself and not an absolute path to where on the systems those files have been/will be installed.